# How can I read process getInputstream?

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I use process builder and process ( with the ffmpeg), and I have to redirect the ffmpeg output to the java input. I wrote this short code, but the inputstream is empty anyways...

```
public class Ffmpegtest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] cmd = {"ffmpeg ","-i ","output2.mp4 ","-f ","mp4 ", "-"};
    InputStream stream;
    try {
        stream = new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList(cmd)).start().getInputStream();
        System.out.println(stream.available()); // still 0
        byte[] kilo = new byte[1024];
        int i = stream.read(kilo,0,1024);
        while(i != -1){
            System.out.println("read "+1024);
            i = stream.read(kilo,0,1024);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try your code ... with something simpler than ffmpeg? Meaning: maybe you first want to make sure that your program is able to read from stdin at all; so start testing using the echo command for example. On the other hand; did you verify on the command line that your options to ffmpeg actually trigger it to write to stdout?

Comment: nope, because I have to use it. It's not my choice.

Comment: I didn't suggest to do something different in the end. I asked you to confirm that the parts of your puzzle work independent of each other. It doesn't make sure to "integrate A+B" ... when you are not 100% sure that A and B each do what you think they should do. And that is what I suggested you to do: verify A, then verify B; and then verify A+B.

Answer (score 4):

When I run:

```
ffmpeg -i file -f mp4 -
```

stdout is empty. However, stderr says:

```
ffmpeg version N-74516-g99b9f01 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --samples=/Users/ronaldbultje/Movies/fate-suite-ff --enable-libvpx
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 58.100 / 56. 58.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 34.100 /  5. 34.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, ivf, from 'file.ivf':
  Duration: 00:00:00.01, start: 0.002000, bitrate: 178292 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp9 (Profile 0) (VP90 / 0x30395056), yuv420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
[mp4 @ 0x7f95aa800000] muxer does not support non seekable output
Output #0, mp4, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 ( [0][0][0] / 0x0020), yuv420p, 640x480, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 1k fps, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.58.100 mpeg4
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp9 (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

The key here is "muxer does not support non seekable output". Choose a different output format that supports streaming (e.g. mpegts), or choose a file output instead of stdout. As a more general java rule, always check stdout as well as stderr when using Process.

Comment: Well, I change mp4 to mpeg, and it prints the correct output to the cmd. But in the java, there is still zero the availability of the input stream.

Comment: You still need to read the error stream, it will block progress of Process.

Answer (score 1):

It's always tricky to interface with other processes standard streams from Java. If you want to consume the output of ffmpeg you need your main thread to wait for the other process to end, and should always listen for both stdout and stderr. In the following demo two temporary files are used (don't forget to cleanup and check return code):

```
public class App {
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    File stdout = File.createTempFile("ffmpeg-out", ".txt");
    File stderr = File.createTempFile("ffmpeg-err", ".txt");
    int result = ProcessBuilder.command(args)
                  .redirectOutput(stdout)
                  .redirectError(stderr)
                  .start()
                  .waitFor();
    // Now examine result and use stdout/stderror
  }
}
```